# Find factorials using BigInteger in java?

Tags: java, biginteger

I am trying to find the factorial of t numbers and input for each number n is provided by the user.The constraints are;

```
1 < t <= 100
1 < n <= 100
```

My code is :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class fact {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int t = 0, i = 0;
         BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
         BigInteger x1 = BigInteger.ONE;
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         t = sc.nextInt();
         BigInteger a[] = new BigInteger[t];

        for(i = 0; i < t; i++) {
           a[i] = BigInteger.valueOf(sc.nextInt());
        }

        for(i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            while(!a[i].equals(x1)) {
               result = result.multiply(a[i]);
               a[i].subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
            }
            System.out.println(result);
            result = x1;
        }
    }
}
```

I am receiving no errors for the above code it compiles fine and when I execute it just keeps on getting input and no output is printed.

Comment: As you probably realize compilation is not an indication of anything beyond syntatic correctness. Your code is almost impossible to follow. However, what initial `t` are you entering?

Comment: So you want the product, not the factorial. Or the product of factorials, it's not clear. Given n is limited you don't need a BigInteger to store it. In fact a `byte` will do.  Your `a[i].subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1));` doesn't do anything.

Comment: You don't actually need an array for what you are doing but I suspect your problem is that you have an infinite loop.  I suggest you step through your code in your debugger and you should be able to see what the problem is.

Comment: I want the factorial of each number entered where t is the number of inputs and a[i] has list of numbers and factorial should be printed for each one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
a[i].subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
```

Since [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)s are immutable, [`subtract()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#subtract(java.math.BigInteger)) returns a new `BigInteger`. You need to store the result, or you will get an endless loop. Change to

```
a[i] = a[i].subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
```