# Multiplication of big numbers (finding factorial of 100)

Tags: java, arrays, multiplication

I want to find value of 100! and since any of the data types doesnt support this range of numbers I used an array to find the result

The logic of my program is

```
for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
    {
        carry=0;
        for(int j=799;j>=0;j--)
        {
            ar[j]=ar[j]+carry;
            ar[j]=ar[j]*i;
            carry=ar[j]/10;
            ar[j]=ar[j]%10;
        }
    }
```

Here I considered the max no:of digits is 800(and in array 0 to 799).

But when I print the resulting array like this

```
    int flag=0;
    for(int i=0;i<800;i++)
    {
        if(ar[i]==0&&flag==0)
            ;
        else
        {
            System.out.print(ar[i]);
            flag=1;
        }
    }
```

It shows nothing

Can i know where I have gone wrong??

Comment: What is wrong with the code that you have now? You haven't described the problem.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a BigInteger?

Comment: Can i have it more clear @assylias.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854456/find-factorials-using-biginteger-in-java

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you forgot to

```
ar[799] = 1;
```

before you start the loop with the multiplication: a product is initialized with 1.

But the multiplication loop is incorrect, too:

```
 for(int j=799;j>=0;j--){
        ar[j]=ar[j]*i;
        ar[j]=ar[j]+carry;
        carry=ar[j]/10;
        ar[j]=ar[j]%10;
 }
```

The carry must be added *after* multiplying the next digit...

Answer (score -1):

BigInteger is a built-in Java type that you can use out of the box.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.